# PHP - counter in for each loop not updating

Tags: php, loops, foreach, counter

I am looping through an array of products and for each iteration i call a function `theFunction`

```
$products = array (
    //...
    //...
);
$count = count($products);

$i = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    theFunction($id, $name, $i);
    $i++;
    if($i == $count){
        // complete
    }
}
```

Then inside this function i have a couple of other loops with a counter whereby i need to differentiate what happens if it is the first in the loop. To do this I use `$counter` and if it is 1 then it processes `task 2` otherwise it should always process `task 3`

```
function theFunction( $id, $name, $key ){

    $design = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    $collection = $design->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $p) {

        // do task 1...

        // if success/exists then proceed...
        if(file_exists('new_name.jpg')) {

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId());
            $new_array = array( $key => $name.'.jpg' );

            $counter = 1;
            foreach($new_array as $label => $img){
                if($counter === 1 ){
                    // do task 2
                }else{
                    // do task 3
                }

                $counter++;
            }

            $product->save();

        }

    }

}
```

At the moment the counter is always set at 1 and never increases so it always processes task 2 on each iteration

Comment: Could not replicate the issue: http://ideone.com/Q7VBmr

Answer (score 1):

`$new_array = array( $key => $name.'.jpg' )` will only ever have one item, so you'll never reach `task 3` because the `foreach ($new_array as ...)` will only execute once.

I have no idea what you intended `$new_array` to contain, so I cannot make a suggestion on how to fix the issue.  Your script is doing exactly what you told it to do, it's just that you misunderstood your `foreach` input.

Answer (score 0):

$counter is a local variable within the function, being created only within the function, and will be destroyed when the function returns.

I suggest passing the counter in as a parameter, and then returning it, allowing you to retain the value

eg in your function definition:

```
function theFunction( $id, $name, $key, $counterValue ){
    //stuff
    return $counterValue;
}
```

And then when calling the function

```
$counter = theFunction($id, $name, $i, $counter);
```

Don't forget to set $counter = 0; BEFORE your main (not in the function) foreach loop